# Vertical Code Formatting in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, monodevelop

I have been through the code formatting options in MonoDevelop and I am trying to get my code to vertically align.

I have been able to get the Access Modifiers, etc to line up, but I would like to get the variable names and their values, equal signs and values to align.

This is what I have:

[image: example of current autoformatting]

And this is what I am going for:

[image: example of desired autoformatting]

It seems trivial but helps me keep my code clean.

***Is there a setting I have missed?***

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an option for this in monodevelop.  Honestly, I used monodevelop for about a year, and there were just too many things it didn't do.  I switched to VS Code and then Visual Studio for Mac for all my development, and it's... it's just so much better.  VS Code and VS Mac both can use the CodeAlignment plugin for this task.